# Creating Variables in Advance to Use in Loops (?)

Tags: java, eclipse, performance

Which one of these two is more 'efficient':

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = i * 2;
}
```

or -

```
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = i * 2;
}
```

(Just an example)

*I understand they are different in essence - so please do not address the difference in their use.*

In a case where both would prove to do the same thing - will creating the `x` variable multiple times be a less efficient method rather than just creating it once and simply reassigning its value?

Comment: If you don't care about the semantic differences, and only want the performance differences - this is something to profile, though I don't think you will notice any performance differences, as the compiler will likely optimize it so that it's not making a new `x` every time. However, I will advise to code what you mean, not code for a vague sense of optimization.

Comment: Given that the code that reuses `x` has a risk of reusing an old value for `x`, it could be considered safer to create a new instance in the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in this case, with the way compilers are, there is no performance difference.

I prefer the first approach from a readability point of view, but that's something to be discussed elsewhere.

However, as a bonus section to this answer:

```
for (int x = 0; x < calculateUserCountFromDatabaseOrSomething(); x++) {
   //Do stuff
}
```

In the above case, this will be a performance issue since the `calculateUserCountFromDatabaseOrSomething()` method is going to be called on every iteration of the loop.  This is something that definitely needs to be considered when writing software.

Comment: So it would be better to assign the value returned by the method (Given that it won't change during the loop) to a variable and use that instead of calling the method every time? That is understandable, but I didn't know that using a method in such a way would result in multiple calls to said method. I guess using the `size()` parameter of Lists in this manner isn't a good practice?

Comment: Yes, you should define a variable above the loop for method calls.  I know this is not specific to your question, but I think it is worth saying nonetheless.

Comment: @Acidic: Just to be a smart-### I often write `for(int i = getTheInitialCount(); --i >= 0;){ ... }`.

Comment: @Mike: do you often find yourself unemployed? ;)

Comment: @jkschneider: Snarky quip? Been with Pharsight for about 15 years. Key developer on 4 or 5 scientific desktop apps. Before that consulting since early 80s. Before that, CS professor. I know where snippy attitudes like that come from - young professors.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency should be the same - I'd expect the byte code to be exactly the same.

However, what you should *really* care about is the readability and maintainability of the code, which is better in the first approach, as it limits the scope of `x` more - making it clearer where it will be used.

You should almost *always* care about readability over performance until you have *evidence* that not only is the less-readable alternative faster, but that the most readable solution is not fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a definitive answer check this:

http://livingtao.blogspot.com/2007/05/myth-defining-loop-variables-inside.html

This conducts a byte code comparison of the results of compilation.

The answer is *no difference* by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of the objects. For example if `X` is String it will make little difference. If for example `X` is some sort of Map, you can initialize it once, and clear it every time in the end of iteration. In the case `X` is int, it really does not matter, in terms of efficiency. Mind the scope of the variable, declaring it outside the loop suggests an intention, that it will be used after that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're allocating space for only one int instead of ten ints, in the second scenario, it should be faster. However, in reality the java compiler will almost certainly optimize this heavily to the point where microbenchmarks would say they took the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not created multiple times:

```
for ( A; B; C ) {
    D;
}
```

the execution is this:
A - (B - D - C) ... (B - D - C) until B became false

Answer (score 0):

No performance benefits, both are same,  but ,its better practice to declare your variables in as *narrow a scope as possible*, so as to make it more readable and clear.

**Variables should only exist within the scope that they are used**